# Can't retrieve UserId from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I have created a new class that I want to manage a few things, one of which is to get the User Id `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`. I get this error message

> CS0103    The name 'User' does not exist in the current context

And this is my code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

public string UserId
{
    get
    {
        return User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }
}
```

[image]

I was expecting intellisense to pick up the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` `GetUserId` method, but I get the error below.

What am I doing wrong and why can't it pick up the `UserId` from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `HttpContext.Current.User`like this:

```
public string UserId
{
    get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(); }
}
```

Because based on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx):

> if you want to use the members of IPrincipal from an ASP.NET code-behind module, you must include a reference to the System.Web namespace in the module and a fully qualified reference to both the currently active request/response context and the class in System.Web that you want to use. For example, in a code-behind page you must specify the fully qualified name HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.

As an another note, you can also use the C# 6+ new feature called [expression-bodied property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) like this:

```
public string UserId => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the current active request/response context to be able to access the User property.

Comment: I used this HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(); and it works, would you say this is the correct method to use?